# Put back part of searched pattern in regex

Tags: regex, scheme, racket

I am trying to replace ? with "An " if subsequent word starts with a vowel

```
(define (f str)
  (println (regexp-replace* #rx"\\? [aeiou]"  str "An ")))

(f "? apple.")
```

It works but it takes away 'a' of 'apple'. The output is:

```
"An pple."
```

Using '&' replaces entire search pattern back in string:

```
(println (regexp-replace* #rx"\\? [aeiou]"  str "An &"))
```

Output:

```
"An ? apple."
```

How can I just put back 'a' or whatever vowel was found at the start of word?

Comment: Try a capture group for `([aeiou])` then write it back in the replacement. Or, if the engine supports it use a lookahead assertion `(?=[aeiou])`

Comment: Both work but output remains the same.

Comment: Why is these brackets escaped `\\[\\?\\]` and not these `[aeiou]` is this BRE flavor? In a real sense, the regex is this `\? (?=[aeiou])` and replace is `An ` _or_ `\? ([aeiou])` and replace is `An $1`

Comment: Its only "\\?" . I have corrected the question. Racket language needs \\? rather than \?

Comment: If it's a Java or PCRE style engine, then one of the two regex in my comment will work.

Comment: (?=[aeiou])"  str "An ")  works! (Other commands do not work properly). Thanks. You can put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a real sense, the regex is this

Find: `\? (?=[aeiou])`
Replace: `An`

or  if you can replace back a capture group

Find: `\? ([aeiou])`
Replace: `An $1`

Comment: (regexp-replace* #rx"\\? ([aeiou])"  "? apple." "An $1") produces "An $1pple."   This works properly: (regexp-replace* #rx"\\? (?=[aeiou])"  "? apple." "An ") output is: "An apple."

Comment: Kind of strange. Somehow it should support capture group reference in the replacement. Sometimes a backslash is used instead of $, usually like `\1` but I don't know their usage. Good Luck!